# JQuery To Change TeleRik RadGrid Row Color

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am attempting to use this to change the row color to white

```
row.cells[1].css('background-color', '#B3B3B3');
```

I get an error of

> Uncaught TypeError: row.cells[1].css is not a function

What is the appropriate way to achieve this restult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Attributes if you want to change the color from code behind.

```
row.cells[1].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: #B3B3B3");
```

Or assign a class

```
row.Cells[1].CssClass = "myClass";

<style>
    .myClass {
        background-color: #B3B3B3
    }
</style>
```

UPDATE

So if you want it on a button click, do it like this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].CssClass = "myClass";
}
```

Comment: I use the code for the css class - but the row is not changed?

Comment: When and where are you trying this? Because I used the same code as you posted: `row.cells[1]`

Comment: $("#btnUpdateThis").on('click', function (event) {
        row.cells[1].innerHTML = row.cells[1].innerHTML + ' - ' + $('#<%=txtCurrentText.ClientID %>').val();
        row.cells[1].CssClass = "myClass";
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');        
    });

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was talking about code behind code while you were using javascript. Anyway the color does not change because it is changed in the front-end. Then right after there is a PostBack so all changes done with javascipt are lost. So if you set it programatically the color will change.

Comment: In webforms when you click a button there will be a form post to the server. That is called a PostBack. But this is basically the same as reloading the page. So everything you do to elements on that page with javascript are lost since the server does not know about those changes and rebuild the page to it's original state.